# getView() and getActivity() not found

Tags: java, android, onclick

I set up a basic `onClickListener`, but `Andoid Studio` cannot resolve `getActivity()` or `getView()`. It will resolve `getActivity()` with a static import  `import static android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity` but that seems odd, and doesn't work for `getView()`.

here's my code

```
//get the button view
    startButton = getView().findViewById(R.id.startButton);

    //set a onclick listener for when the button gets clicked
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //Start new list activity
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SeccondActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainIntent);

        }
    }
```

Comment: is this code in fragment or not??

Comment: can you post the whole class?

Comment: We need to see the class declaration.

Comment: try to remove static import and then press `ctrl+shift+O`

Comment: Try replacing `getActivity()` with `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your class intended to be a Fragment? If so, add this on the top of you class:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

And the class definition has to extend it. For example:

```
public class MyClass extends Fragment {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The activity is not available in onCreate() for Fragments. Add this code in the onCreateView() function, and replace getView() with view.